# Pandas annotate dataframe hist

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
df = { 'id' : pd.Series([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4])}

num_id = df['id'].value_counts().hist(bins=2)
```

I an get a nice histogram with the count of number of ids that fall into each bin.

Question is, how do i add annotations to each bar to show the count? It could be in the middle with white text.

I know there is an `ax` parameter that we can specify in `hist()` but i am not sure how.

[image]

Comment: [`ax.text`](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html) is what you need. You can tie the x and y coordinates to the bin edges `hist` returns...

Comment: Could you show how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are (with the `import` statements, just in case):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
freq, bins, _ = ax.hist(df['id'].value_counts(), 2, facecolor='skyblue')
ax.grid(True)
for i, n in enumerate(freq):
    ax.text(bins[i]+0.5, 2, n)
ax.set_xlabel('Bins')
ax.set_ylabel('Freq')
plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram, with Text]